# mplleaflet - how resolve problem whit XAxis?

Tags: python

I'm trying to execute code:
The code I found as answer on question "Map and scatter not working (Mplleaflet)".

```
import mplleaflet
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

lats = [54.3256, 53.2692, 53.8242, 53.2178]
lons = [2.9356, 3.6278, 2.9453, 3.2203] 

fig = plt.figure()    #This is missing in your code.
plt.plot(lons, lats, 'r.')

#And after this call the funtion:

mplleaflet.display(fig=fig)
#It will display the matplotlib object created by plot function
```

but I have got an error: "'XAxis' object has no attribute '_gridOnMajor'"

I updated matplotlib but it doesn't help. How may I resolve the problem ?

Bellow Traceback
Traceback (most recent call last):

Input In [2] in <cell line: 12>
mplleaflet.display(fig=fig)

File C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\mplleaflet_display.py:153 in display
html = fig_to_html(fig, **kwargs)

File C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\mplleaflet_display.py:84 in fig_to_html
exporter.run(fig)

File C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\mplleaflet\mplexporter\exporter.py:51 in run
self.crawl_fig(fig)

File C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\mplleaflet\mplexporter\exporter.py:118 in crawl_fig
self.crawl_ax(ax)

File C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\mplleaflet\mplexporter\exporter.py:123 in crawl_ax
props=utils.get_axes_properties(ax)):

File C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\mplleaflet\mplexporter\utils.py:267 in get_axes_properties
'axes': [get_axis_properties(ax.xaxis),

File C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\mplleaflet\mplexporter\utils.py:231 in get_axis_properties
props['grid'] = get_grid_style(axis)

File C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\mplleaflet\mplexporter\utils.py:241 in get_grid_style
if axis._gridOnMajor and len(gridlines) > 0:

AttributeError: 'XAxis' object has no attribute '_gridOnMajor'

Answer (score 0):

This appear to be an internal library problem to quote from an answer from [here](https://github.com/plotly/plotly.py/issues/2913);

> oh sorry that's in a different repository that has the same issue! It's a really simple fix though (axis._gridOnMajor -> axis._major_tick_kw['gridOn']) and the lines are listed above. I could fix it, but I don't have reference code to test with (I've never used plotly!)